# при создании дочернего процесса с помощью fork(), вызове execvp и переназначении stdin/sdout с помощью pipe, read блокируется на чтении

Tags: c, unix, exec, pipes

Нужно запустить скрипт с помощью exec, передат ему значение в ввод и прочитать из его вывода, но при чтении операция блокируется, не могу опнять почему. Дело не в скрипте, он работает правильно(обычное эхо), если вызов exec отсутствует все тоже правильно работает. Не могу найти ошибку.

код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>



int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int pipe_in[2];
    int pipe_out[2];
    pipe(pipe_in);
    pipe(pipe_out);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
        close(pipe_in[1]);
        close(pipe_out[0]);
        dup2(pipe_in[0], 0);
        dup2(pipe_out[1], 1);
        char* arg[3];
        arg[0] = "php";
        arg[1] = "/home/anton/a.php";
        arg[2] = NULL;
        if (execvp(arg[0], arg) < 0)
            _exit(0);
    }
    close(pipe_in[0]);
    close(pipe_out[1]);
    char buf[10];
    write(pipe_in[1], "1111", 4);
    read(pipe_out[0], buf, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

скрипт

```
<?php

$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo $line;
?>
```

Comment: попробуйте `write(pipe_in[1], "1111\n", 5);`, `fgets` же до конца строки читает

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо, помогло